# How to make moodle Banners get information from the course

Tags: html, moodle

I created many courses on Moodle, and they all come with a default Banner, as follows:
[image]

The yellow text is supposed to be the course name, and the white one, the teacher of the course.

Right now, I do each and every course Banner manually.

I have tried searching for dynamic banners, and all I could find is a video showing it's possible, not how it's done.

Right now, the code for the Banner is like this:

```
<div id="Aristides"></div>

<script>
    var largura = window.screen.width;

    var turma = 'Turma de Teste';

    var professor = 'Professor de Teste';

    var imgSvg = ''; <!-- any svg, left empty for better question size-->


    if (largura > 1300) {
        var element = document.getElementById('Aristides');
        element.innerHTML = '<div style="border-radius: 10px; background: linear-gradient(81deg, rgba(250,157,8,1) 3%, rgba(175,109,3,1) 5%, rgba(14,86,126,1) 5.1%, rgba(95,188,236,1) 47%, rgba(82,164,207,1) 50%, rgba(95,188,236,1) 50.1%, rgba(14,86,126,1) 94.9%, rgba(175,109,3,1) 95%, rgba(250,157,8,1) 97%); width: 100%; display: flex;"><a href="https://storyset.com/business" style="max-width: 450px; min-width: 450px; padding-left: 5%;">' + imgSvg + '</a><div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; justify-content: space-between; max-height: 450px;"><h1 style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; margin-top: 40px; font-size: 52px; font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, serif; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgb(0,0,0,0.3);"> Bem-vindo(a) à Sala Virtual! </h1><h2 style="color: rgba(255,185,8); font-weight: bold; text-align: center; justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 40px; font-size: 38px; font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, serif; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgb(0,0,0,0.3);">' + turma + '</h2><h3 style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 50px; font-size: 22px; font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgb(0,0,0,0.3);"> Professor(a): ' + professor + '</h3></div></div>'
    } else {
        var element = document.getElementById('Aristides');
        element.innerHTML = '<div style="border-radius: 10px; background: linear-gradient(175deg, rgba(250,157,8,1) 3%, rgba(175,109,3,1) 5%, rgba(14,86,126,1) 5.3%, rgba(95,188,236,1) 47%, rgba(82,164,207,1) 50%, rgba(95,188,236,1) 50.3%, rgba(14,86,126,1) 94.7%, rgba(175,109,3,1) 95%, rgba(250,157,8,1) 97%); width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;"><a href="https://storyset.com/business" style="max-width: 268px; min-width: 270px;">' + imgSvg + '</a><div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; max-width: 260px; justify-content: space-between; max-height: 450px;"><h1 style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 30px; font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, serif;"> Bem-vindo(a) à Sala Virtual! </h1><h2 style="color: rgba(255,185,8); font-weight: bold; text-align: center; justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 20px; font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, serif;">' + turma + '</h2><h3 style="color: #fff; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 25px; font-size: 13px; font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;"> Professor(a): ' + professor + '</h3></div></div>'
    }
</script>
```

Is there any way I can make it automatically have the complete course name and the teacher name on the banner on the designated texts, and make it default like my current one?

Comment: I'm not a front end developer, but I think the correct way to do do this is by passing the course name to a moustache template and overriding the template. Unless its a custom theme or course format? https://moodledev.io/docs/guides/templates#overriding-templates-in-a-theme

Comment: I'm using the Moove theme, and I'm using the grid format for the course, i don't think those change anything. I'm currently searching if I can make a plugin to use a API to get data (teacher and name) from the course and later on use this plugin data on the banner. Not sure I'm on the right path though